# VS 2022 c# 'type or namespace name 'DllExport' could not be found'

Tags: namespaces, dllexport

This is from a c# dll from GitHub that is in use by many people so it should compile but this line
[DllExport(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
gives these errors

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DllExport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DllExportAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

That is the only line in the code with an error.

```
using System;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Windows.Services.Store;
...
[DllExport(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered with your specific line of code there

```
[DllExport(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

DllExport is a function from the UnmanagedExports library, so you just need to add:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
```